# Stop resizing screen when going out of the VM

Tags: vmware

Currently I'm working with a Windows XP virtual machine, and each time I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to work with the host machine, the guest gets resized to fit a smaller window.

I've tried changing all of the options as indicated [here](https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-09956D63-AB96-4610-874D-B80CDA9D5734.html) and also tried what [this answer says](https://superuser.com/questions/300134/ubuntu-screen-resolution-doesnt-fit-size-of-monitor-vmware), but it doesn't change the behaviour: it still resizes.

I also looked at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/109829/how-do-i-stop-vmware-player-from-resizing) answer, but I don't really want to uninstall VMWare tools, as it helps a lot when transferring files.

What I'd like is to simply let the VM have the original resolution, and when I zoom out of it, have scrollbars to scroll to the right / bottom instead of resizing the VM.

Is it possible?

I'm using VMWare Workstation 10.0.1

Comment: I think VMWare only looks for the right CTRL-ALT. Try using the left CTRL-ALT with enter. Does that work?

Comment: @LPChip I am using the left `Ctrl` key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to View=>Autoresize=>Center guest
Now you will see the guest in a small window.
now inside the guest OS go to resolution and set it to what your monitor is about.
Then apply that and yeah! it is fixed!